# Makefile parsing a string

Tags: string, parsing, variables, makefile

I want to parse a string in a Makefile to be included in a .c file.
Due to circumstances beyound my controll there are reduntant entries in many files.  The format of the entries can vary slightly. I can change stuff downstream of the original definition which makes things more difficult.  So here is what I have:

Here is 3 examples of what I can get for input from a calling makefile (the numbers are random).

ORIG1=S12a1234A5678

ORIG2=S123a1234A5678

ORIG3=S123123456789

So I am interested in the last 9 digits and would format them as follows.

Output should be assigned to another set of makefile variables by insterting a '0' before the 5th digit from the end of the string if it contains an 'A' otherwise grab the last nine digits.
OUT1=12340A5678

OUT2=12340A5678

OUT3=123456789

It is more desireable if the output can be created in the Makefile instead of shelling out.
I tried and failed miserably with sed.  Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: sed **is** "shelling out"

Answer (score 1):

```
targ:
    @echo $(ORIG1) | sed '/A/s/\(.*\)\(\([0-9][^0-9]*\)\{5\}\)/\10\2/;s/.*\(\([0-9\][^0-9]*\)\{9\}\)/\1/' >> destination.c
```

Notice that this transformation takes place in a command, so it's handled by sed in a shell.

You *can* do it with Make functions, without invoking any shell, but you really *shouldn't*. Make wasn't designed for this kind of parsing, so the solution would be hideous.

Comment: This is what I ended up with:

Comment: To create the parameter I used this statment in the header portion of the Makefile:

OUT1=$(shell echo $(ORIG1) | sed -n '/A/y/[a-z]/[A-Z]/;s/A/0A/;s/.*\(\([0-9\][^0-9]*\)\{9\}\)/\1/p');


This works for my needs when the "A" is there and when it is not by 1st making it all uppercase, then change the 'A' to '0A' and lastly grabbing the last 9 characters in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the asker has moved on after 3 years, but if anyone else is interested here is a modular way of doing the task w/ make.

```
hasA     = $(findstring A,$(1))
lastN    = $(shell echo -n $(1) | tail -c $(2))
firstN   = $(shell echo -n $(1) | head -c $(2))
smack0   = $(1)0$(2)
AFormat  = $(call smack0,$(call firstN,$(1),4),$(call lastN,$(1),5))
myFormat = $(if $(call hasA,$(1)),$(call AFormat,$(1)),$(1))
func9    = $(call myFormat,$(call lastN,$(1),9))

# AFormat   = smack0 (firstN (string,4),lastN (string,5))
# myFormat  = hasA (string) ? AFormat (string) : string
# func9     = myFormat (last9 (string))

test:
    @echo hasA     "(1234B66547) ->" $(call hasA,1234B66547)
    @echo lastN    "(RosieODonnellSuperManVelociraptor123456789,9) ->" $(call lastN ,RosieODonnellSuperManVelociraptor123456789,9)
    @echo smack0   "(1234,0,ABCD) ->" $(call smack0,1234,ABCD)
    @echo func9    "(S12a1234A5678 ) ->" $(call func9,S12a1234A5678)
    @echo func9    "(S123a1234A5678) ->" $(call func9,S123a1234A5678)
    @echo func9    "(S123123456789 ) ->" $(call func9,S123123456789)
```

admittedly you could see this as a variation of just writing one script
that automates the task of "func9" & calling that w/ `$(shell func9 $(STR))` but who knows, maybe you don't want to bother saving a tiny script that only has relevance to some make recipe & you'd rather save it in some helper makefile.